# Is there a way more pythonic way to duplicate the n-th element of a list in python? E.g. using list comprehension

Tags: python, list

I can achieve what I'm after with a simple for loop, but feel there's a much more pythonic way of achieving the same goal, I just can't figure it out. For the n-th element in a list (and sometimes n-th and m-th, more than one index), I would like to duplicate that element and have ever other element move down by one.

For example, this script takes the element at index 4 and 5 and duplicates it:

```
 old_list = [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10]
 new_list = []
    
 for idx, value in enumerate(old_list):
     if idx==4 or idx==5:
         new_list.append(value)
         new_list.append(value)
     else:
         new_list.append(value)
```

Output:
`new_list = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 5, 6, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10]`

The script above isn't optimal, I'm sure. But demonstrates my objective.

Edit: Added more clarity to problem statement. To answer some questions,

- In my case the list always has 48 elements, but I'm curious as to any length
- I'd like to duplicate any stated element index (sometimes two indexes, sometimes none). In this example, elements 4 and 5 (which could be swapped out for any two others via a variable instead of hard coded numbers)

Comment: FYI, even with this code, you can simplify that a lot. You _always_ want to append, just sometimes you want to append _twice_. So always have one unconditional append (no `else`), and one conditional append (simple `if`).

Comment: Your title says "only the n-th",  your text says "every n-th", and your code disagrees with both. Please make up your mind and fix.  And how large is your real list and how large is your real n? And do you need a new list or is it ok to modify the existing one?

Comment: My apologies for the confusion. I basically want to duplicate any element at any given position/index. That would be a value stated by a user earlier in the script, and doesn't impact the problem. Sometimes there may be be no duplication, so @deceze comment is a great addition to improve the existing code. The sample code was just to demonstrate my objective, even if I worded is poorly.

The list will always be 48 elements long, and changing the existing list is absolutely fine. I was just curious as to a more pythonic way to address this :)

Comment: It does impact the problem because it does impact potential solutions. I might have better solutions but I can't answer if I don't know what you're asking.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Can you try the following:

```
new_list = [value for idx, value in enumerate(old_list) 
            for __ in range(2 if idx == 4 or idx == 5 else 1)]
```

Comment: This is exactly what I was after. I couldn't get the `for _ in range(2)` part right in my attempted list comprehension. Thank you, this solves my question.

Answer (score 1):

To duplicate just one index:

```
lst = [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10]
lst[4:5] *= 2
print(lst)
```

For an arbitrary index `n`:

```
lst[n:n+1] *= 2
```

If you want to duplicate multiple indices, either do them form largest to smallest, or from smallest to largest and adjust them as needed (increase each by the number of previous duplications).

Answer (score -1):

```
>>> from itertools import chain
>>> old_list = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10]
>>> dup_idx = {4, 5}
>>> list(chain.from_iterable((v, v) if i in dup_idx else (v,) for i, v in enumerate(old_list)))
[0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 4, 5, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10]
```

With the comprehension here, you're basically creating a sequence of tuples, like:

```
(0,), (1,), (2,), (3,), (4, 4), (5, 5), ...
```

`chain.from_iterable` flattens that into one sequence of numbers, and `list` creates an actual list from the iterator.

Alternatively:

```
list(chain.from_iterable((v,) * ((i in dup_idx) + 1) for i, v in enumerate(old_list)))
```

But this is more tricky and error prone. It creates one tuple `(v,)`, then multiplies that tuple by either `1` or `2` (i.e. `(v,) * 1`/`(v,) * 2`). The `1` and `2` are the result of `(i in dup_idx) + 1`. `i in dup_idx` is either `True` or `False`, which act like `1` and `0` respectively; and then `+ 1` gets added to that.

This approach works here, because you only have numbers, but might lead to [surprising results](https://stackoverflow.com/q/240178/476) with mutable objects:

```
>>> t = ([],)
>>> t2 = t * 2
>>> t2
([], [])
>>> t2[0].append('foo')
>>> t2
(['foo'], ['foo'])
```

Comment: I'm curious: you commented *"always have one unconditional append (no else), and one conditional append"*. I think that's the natural order to think of. So I would've written `1 + (i in dup_idx)`. Why didn't you?

Comment: ‍♂️ Who knows…